# Is Youtube's Live Video Permanent URL no longer working?

Tags: youtube, embedding

As a school who has recently begun livestreaming many of our sports, I am trying to bring those livestreams to display on the digital signage around our campus.

Pre-Covid we did this on a more limited scope and we were able to take advance to the bit of URL magic to stream the currently livestreaming event:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=yourChannelid

specifically this that did the autoplay and some other tidbits: https://www.YouTube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=yourChannelid&autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=0&loop=1

This method seems well documented as late as 2021 (maybe 2022... it's been a lot of threads I've been reading through) but all that happens now is a "This Video is unavailable"

Unfortunately we aren't savvy enough to look at a solution that ties into the API to feed our Brightsign players. So back to the question... is YouTube's live video permanent URL no longer working? or am I just missing something obvious?

My thanks!